# Finding the error using Lagrange Interpolation Formula

Tags: numerical-methods, lagrange-interpolation

With what error can $\sqrt{115}$ be approximated, using Lagrange Interpolation formula and the nodes $x_{0}=100,x_{1}=121$ and $x_{2}=144$?

Comment: What do you know about the error formula of quadratic interpolation? What is the value that quadratic interpolation gives for your task?

Comment: I'm sorry, I think this is all I've got from my professor,as a seminary homework...

Comment: What research efforts do you have to show? The wikipedia page contains enough information, the proof for the error formula is linked to wikibooks, your text book or course script should likewise contain some information.